# Create a list from values and a number of repetitions

Tags: python

I try to create list from values and a number of repetitions:
from example:

values = [1, 2, 3]

weights = [3, 2, 1]

result = [1,1,1,2,2,3]

I try:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, [[v] * w for v, w in zip(values, weights)])
```

Is there a simpler option to do this in one pass?

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension can do that. It's debatable whether it's simpler:

```py
[value for value, weight in zip(values, weights) for repetition in range(weight)]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sum([[v] * w for v, w in zip(values, weights)],[])
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's also 2 passes

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a regular for loop instead of list comprehension then you can do this in one pass using the following code:

```
values = [1,2,3]
weights = [3,2,1]
out = []
for v,w in zip(values, weights):
  out.extend([v] * w)
print(out)
```

Comment: There is option to do that by list comprehension?

Comment: @galleshem The only way to do this using list comprehension (that I know of), is to iterate for the value of each weight. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71347777/11423131) where they did that.